# Prevent certain cells/columns from being sorted

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I would like to be able to sort this table based upon columns C, D, E and F (RawDmg, GScore, EScore, RScore). However, when I do apply this sort it messed up the bordered info box to the right. Is it possible have it so that only columns A to F sort while the box stays in its place? I tried freeze panes and cell protection but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

I would appreciate any ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

select columns A:F and use filter or filter view:

[image]